# Using Fabric in Python, trying to run tsch commands on remote bash server

Tags: python, unix, fabric

Sorry if that Title is confusing. I am running a remote python script over the local network using Fabric:

```
#Path to file being run
env.source = 'c/yadda/yadda'
env.file = 'run_tests.py'
env.set = 'source ~USERNAME/ENVIRONMENT'

#create the task of changing the directory and running the test file from there
def link():
    print('Connecting to remote computer and setting envirnoment...')
    run ('%s' % env.set)
    run ('cd %s && ./%s' % (env.source, env.file))


--- The env.set is used to bring the Python version up to a more recent version so that the file commands work (open with was causing problems).
```

THE PROBLEM is that the env.set has tsch commands such as setenv which, when run in the Bash shell, give errors. Is there any way that I can write the above to incorporate tsch commands?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I solved it myself :)

Setting in the top:

```
env.shell = '/bin/rbash -l -c'
```

I got around this environment issue.